# How is the ghc runtime support for profiling implemented?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I did not find much  documentation in the commentery. Are there any good blog posts or similarly on this?

Comment: After a relatively fruitless google search, I'm afraid GHC HQ is too busy implementing and improving it to blog about it.

Comment: I think most of is still pretty much as described in the [Sansom & Jones paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.6277). Is there anything specific you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks for the reference! That should be an answer. I think rwh mentions that some optimizations are incompatible with profiling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best source for information on the profiling framework might still be the [original paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.6277) by Patrick Sansom and Simon Peyton Jones. Additional details can be found in Sansom's [PhD thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.3049) as well as the [later paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.8158) adding a formal specification. Simon Marlow also spoke about a few recent changes in the GHC Status Update at [Haskell Implementors' Workshop 2011](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HaskellImplementorsWorkshop/2011#Programme).

The idea behind cost-centre profiling is to annotate the expression tree with "cost centre" nodes, so for example with `-auto-all` the program will have annotations like follows:

```
fib n = {-# SCC foo #-} (case n of
                           0 -> 0
                           1 -> 1
                           n -> fib (n-1) + fib (n-2))
```

At runtime when entering `fib`, the program would look at the current "cost centre stack" and add "foo" to the top. This would be reversed once the evaluation exits the scope of the SCC annotation again. A bit of magic ensures that if, say, `n` happens to be a lazy value and the program needs to execute its code, the cost centre appropriate for *that* code is restored where necessary.

This infrastructure is then used for both time as well as space profiling:

1. A timer will check the cost-centre stack periodically. Every time a certain cost-centre stack is found, this counts as a "tick". In the end, the RTS will estimate the amount of time per cost-centre stack from the count of its ticks, giving you a time profile.
2. Every time an object is allocated, the program saves back a pointer to the cost-centre stack that was current at that point in time. This enables the garbage collector to provide a statistic of how many bytes were resident, broken down by allocation site.

As requested in the comment, a few words on optimization: For obvious reasons the framework can not allow optimizations that move non-constant costs from one cost centre to the other, forcing the optimizer to be quite pessimistic at times. For example, in the above example the current release GHC will *not* be able to unbox the return value, meaning that each recursive call do an unnecessary heap-allocation.

As a rule of thumb, one should not count on any code transformations happening *across* a SCC annotation. When in doubt, it is better to annotate a function sufficiently high in the call-stack, so the performance-critical bits do not get annotated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this paper](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/threadscope.pdf) by Jones, Marlow & Singh useful, depending on what you want to accomplish. It includes practices for profiling GHC programs in a parallel context and contains some case studies that you might find useful.